# Best way to implement a 2 for 1 offer on selected nodes?

Tags: 6, ubercart

I have a drupal 6 ubercart site that I need to add a two for 1 offer on (for selected nodes). I've installed and tried the discount_alt module but this just seemed really buggy and was not doing what I am looking for.

Now i am thinking of invoking some hook on the checkout process so I can see if they have two of the same items in the basket, and if so, just slash 50% off the price.

I can't seem to find the right hook to do this tho? Any ideas where the best place to start would be?